# How to compare the hash-password with ordinary one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have big trouble in verifying the hash password from the database with the ordinary one coming from the login page.
How to validate a user by comparing this two passwords.Here is my code for registration page:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SHA384CryptoServiceProvider sh = new SHA384CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] plainbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text);
    var sha = sh.ComputeHash(plainbytes);
    byte[] hashbytes = sh.Hash;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RegisterUser",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter param = null;
    param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
    param.Value = TextBox1.Text;
    param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    param.Value = BitConverter.ToString(hashbytes);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label4.Text = "Successfully added account!!!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception adding account"+ex.Message);
    }
    finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
}
```

How to compare this password with the one coming from login page... Help me out guys...

Code for HASH with SALT:-

```
 private static string CreateSalt(int size)

{

    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] buff = new byte[size];

    rng.GetBytes(buff);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);

}

private static string CreatePasswordHash(string pwd, string salt)

{

    string saltAndPwd = String.Concat(pwd, salt);

    string hashedPwd =

    FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(saltAndPwd, "SHA1");

    hashedPwd = String.Concat(hashedPwd, salt);

    return hashedPwd;

}

protected void btnregister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    int saltSize = 5;

    string salt = CreateSalt(saltSize);

    string passwordHash = CreatePasswordHash(txtPassword.Text, salt);

    try

    {

        StoreAccountDetails(txtUserName.Text, passwordHash);

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;

    }

}

private void StoreAccountDetails( string userName,string passwordHash )

{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(@userName, @passwordHash)", conn);

    SqlParameter sqlParam = null;

    sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar,20);

    sqlParam.Value = userName;

    sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@passwordHash ", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);

    sqlParam.Value = passwordHash;

    try

    {

       conn.Open();

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       lblMessage.Text = "User Added Successfully!!!";

    }

    catch( Exception ex )

    {

    throw new Exception("Exception adding account. " + ex.Message);

    }

    finally

    {

       conn.Close();

    }

}

private bool VerifyPassword(string suppliedUserName,string suppliedPassword )

{

     bool passwordMatch=false;

     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "SELECT PasswordHash FROM Users WHERE UserName = @userName", conn );

     SqlParameter sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName",SqlDbType.VarChar,20);

     sqlParam.Value = suppliedUserName;

     try

     {

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Read();

        string dbPasswordHash = reader.GetString(0);

        int saltSize = 5;

        string salt = CreateSalt(saltSize);

        reader.Close();

        string hashedPasswordAndSalt =CreatePasswordHash(suppliedPassword, salt);

        passwordMatch = hashedPasswordAndSalt.Equals(dbPasswordHash);

     }

     catch (Exception ex)

     {

        throw new Exception("Execption verifying password. " +ex.Message);

     }

     finally

     {

        conn.Close();

     }

    return passwordMatch;
 }


protected void btnlogon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    bool passwordVerified=false;

    try

    {

        passwordVerified =VerifyPassword(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;

        return;

    }

    if (passwordVerified == true)

    {



        lblMessage.Text = "Logon successful: User is authenticated";

    }

    else

    {

        lblMessage.Text = "Invalid username or password";

    }

}
```

Comment: And where is comparison actually?

Comment: i updated the comparison logig...can u help me in correcting d code...thnx in advance...

Comment: Can you post the actual code your are using? This is still not correct. I can tell because you use hashbyte in searchtable() and that variable does not exist.

Comment: A simple SHA hash of "mypassword" results in a string much larger than 20 characters. There is no way you can fit the base64'd hashed password in a 20 character field. Change the column size and your code to support larger hashes.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: u r right...i used this table for simple login...i will change it for sure...other than that i will update the code...actually i m trying a few things on the code...thnx again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Now that you updated your code I still see a few problems. You should use a Salt, but first you need your code to actually work. Adding a salt is easy.

A simple SHA hash of "mypassword" results in a string much larger than 20 characters. There is no way you can fit the base64'd hashed password in a 20 character field. Change the column size and your code to support larger hashes.

**Update 2**

Here is the code with the Salt on the hash. You have to update your RegisterUser stored procedure to store the salt along with the username and hashed password. You need a new Salt per user. The salt itself does not need to be hashed or encrypted.

You also need to return the salt from your LogInUser stored procedure.

Read comments below:

```
private byte[] Combine(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
   byte[] c = new byte[a.Length + b.Length]; 
   System.Buffer.BlockCopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.Length); 
   System.Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, c, a.Length, b.Length); 
   return c; 
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    random.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);

    SHA384CryptoServiceProvider sh = new SHA384CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] plainbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text);

    var saltedBytes = Combine (salt, plainbytes);
    var sha = sh.ComputeHash(saltedBytes);

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RegisterUser",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter param = null;
    param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
    param.Value = TextBox1.Text;

    param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128);
    param.Value = Convert.ToBase64String(sha);

    // Store salt to use when comparing.
    param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@salt", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128);
    param.Value = Convert.ToBase64String(salt);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label4.Text = "Successfully added account!!!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception adding account"+ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}

public bool searchtable() 
{           
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LogInUser",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter param = null;
    param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
    param.Value = TextBox1.Text;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();

        // Get the salt hashed password
        string dbpassmatch = reader.GetString(0);

        // Get the salt
        byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String(reader.GetString(1));

        // Recreate the salted hashed password
        byte[] plainbyte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text);
        SHA384CryptoServiceProvider sh = new SHA384CryptoServiceProvider();
        var saltedBytes = Combine (salt, plainbytes);
        var sha = sh.ComputeHash(saltedBytes);            

        // Now it matches what you did in insert.
        String dbpassword = Convert.ToBase64String(sha);

        reader.Close();

        return dbpassword.Equals(dbpassmatch);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception adding account" + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster On my kitchen counter.

Comment: @andrew: i made another page with salt...again got stuck in comparing the salt with hash...can you help me out again?

Comment: @biki Can you update your code to show me how you are using the Salt?

Comment: @biki Wrote the salted version for you

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: your code is working fine except for the fact that its showing the exception- "Index was outside the bounds of the array" when trying to compare...

Answer (score 4):

Simple. You hash the password coming from the login page, and compare the hash code to the hash code in the database.

---

As the text should be handled the same both times, make a single function for that part. Use UTF-8 when converting the text to bytes, the ASCII encoding doesn't handle all characters:

```
public static string HashString(string value) {
  SHA384CryptoServiceProvider sh = new SHA384CryptoServiceProvider();
  byte[] plainbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
  byte[] hash = sh.ComputeHash(plainbytes);
  return BitConverter.ToString(hashbytes);
}
```

Comment: hey can u tell whats wrong in the login page...i am really stuck in it...help me out...

Comment: @biki: You have stored the hash as base64 in the database, so you have to do the same to the password from the login page.

Comment: @Guffa Now that he updated his code, he does not store the password in Base64. BitConverter is not compatible with Base64 classes.

Comment: Not sure this is a very constructive answer. Based on the code he did post he obviously knows he should hash the password store it and then compare the hashes. His code is wrong. That is what he needs help with.

Comment: +1 @AndrewFinnell - then the question is really, 'what's wrong with my code'?

Comment: @biki: I'm not sure that the `Hash` property does. The `ComputeHash` method returns the computed hash code, which you don't use.

Comment: The Hash Property maintains the current state of Hash'ed results. I am guessing it's so you can continue to Hash using the last Hash. He shouldn't use the Hash property because while technically the results will be the same in his code, it is unclear the intention.

Comment: @UpTheCreek He's asked for help on his code in the comments of everyone's question. So that IS the question. Plus he posted code.

Comment: I'd suggest changing BitConverter to Base64. BitConverter adds an undeed '-' character between hex'ed bytes.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: Yes, base64 is more compact, but either works fine. Also, the dashes from the `BitConverter` output can simply be removed as they doesn't carry any information.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell - in that case the question name should be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is pretty bad from a security point of view:

1. Use a salt. Typically a random value(64 bit or more) stored alongside the hash in the db.
2. Use a slow KDF, such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt
   PBKDF2 is easiest, since .net already contains an implementation: [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx)
3. Don't use `Encoding.ASCII`, but `Encoding.UTF8`. Else passwords containing non ASCII characters become very weak.

Then to verify an entered password, read the hash and salt from the db. Hash the candidate password with the salt you read from the db, and compare the hashes.

---

ASP.net also contains a library called [`Membership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx), but I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: @codeln: thnx for the info...i have modified my code with salt...whats wrong in the code?

Comment: @biki `FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile` sucks. Don't use it. `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is much better.

Answer (score 0):

you could do the hashing in the db side, not the application side. that would be the easiest, youll send the password as plain text to the register stored proceudre, it will hash it (with something like sha1)
then you will send the password again when the user performs a login, the stored procedure will look for the username you have sent, then will hash the password and compare it to the password saved during registration.

Comment: and how i am supposed to do that...any idea??

Comment: this should do the trick for encryption: hashbytes(‘sha1’,'password')
thats for the register. then you could do a select which looks something like this: select * from users where userName = _userName and password = hashbytes(‘sha1’,_password)

Comment: that was for sql server and if you are using MySql then: SHA1('password');